# Matrices $P$ such that $A$ is symmetric $\Longrightarrow $ $PAP^{-1}$ is symmetric

Tags: group-theory, matrices

Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the (vector) space of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $Sym_n(\mathbb{R})$ denote the subspace of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ by conjugation. With this action, the orthogonal and scalar matrices leave $Sym_n(\mathbb{R})$ invariant.

**Question:** If $A$ is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ leaving $Sym_n(\mathbb{R})$ invariant under conjugation, is it necessary that $A$ is a product of an orthogonal matrix and a scalar matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the eigenspaces of symmetric matrices are mutually orthogonal, and the eigenspaces of $ASA^{-1}$ are the images under $A$ of the eigenspaces of $S$, and if $A$ isn't a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix, then there are two orthogonal spaces whose image under $A$ aren't orthogonal.

Comment: Your answer is very nice, but it would be better if you could rephrase it.  For example: If $A$ is not a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix then there are two orthonormal vectors $v,w$ such that $Av,Aw$ are not orthogonal. Consider the symmetric matrix $S=vv^t$. Notice that $ASA^{-1}$ has an eigenvector $Av$ associated to $1$ and an eigenvector $Aw$ associated to $0$, but they are not orthogonal. Thus, $ASA^{-1}$ is not symmetric.